# Flask with python selenium

Tags: selenium, flask, gae-python27

When i run my first file newone.py at that time flask server is open and the i press one button and my second file test.py is call and run my function script and test my website testing are complete successful but one file is generated .html but its give null value when i run on flask server its give me this kind of output please give me solution for this

```
this is my main file which name is newone.py

from flask import Flask, render_template
from test import test
from unittest import TestCase
import unittest
from unittest import TestCase
import HTMLTestRunner
from flask import request

app=Flask(__name__)


@app.route('/submit')
def test2():
            return test.testlogin()

@app.route('/view')
def test3():
    return render_template("no.html")


@app.route('/')
def test1():
            return render_template('profile.html')



if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(threaded=False)
    HTMLTestRunner.main()



 and my another file is test.py in this  main function are calling by main file

import unittest
from random import randint
from flask import Flask, render_template
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
from unittest import TestCase, main as unittest_main
import MySQLdb
import HTMLTestRunner



class test(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def testlogin(self):

        # if request.method:'POST'()
        browser = webdriver.Chrome()
        db = MySQLdb.connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "first")
        cursor = db.cursor()
        cursor.execute("select * from login WHERE id = 1")
        results = cursor.fetchall()
        error="in"
        # total_records = len(results)
        # random_id = randint(1,total_records)
        # print(random_id)
        #
        # cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM login WHERE id = %s" % random_id)
        # results = cursor.fetchall()

        if (results):

            for row in results:
                data = row
                print("data[0] is : ", data[0])
                print("data[1] is : ", data[1])
                print("data[2] is : ", data[2])
                # browser = self.browser
                browser.get("http://itechnotion.in/redonno/php/giver/giver/login")
                user = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#txt_church_email')
                user.send_keys(data[1])
                password = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('#txt_church_password')
                password.send_keys(data[2])
                login = browser.find_element_by_css_selector('button')
                login.click()
                browser.close()
                return "ff"
        else:
            assert "No results found." not in browser.page_source


if __name__ == "main":
    HTMLTestRunner.main
```

Comment: what kind of output? please provide your question with the error statement

Comment: i can not get all test cases output in .html file while i am using flask it can not give any kind of error but htmltestrunner.py can not genrate report in flask what should be the reason